# Creating associations by using checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A User can only have two types of Subscriptions: DailySubscription and WeeklySubscription.  When the user is at the new and edit action, I'd like them to check off either of the subscriptions they would like to get.

I'm comfortable using nested fields (as per Ryan Bates' screencast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)) but I think when I add inheritance, it really complicating matters.  **Is there a better way?**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    # type field is defined in the migration for Single Table Inheritance
end

class DailySubscription < Subscription
    # Business logic here 
end

class WeeklySubscription < Subscription
   # Different business logic here 
end
```

My initial efforts with the controller are wacky:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    # I can't use @user. subscriptions.build as Rails doesn't 
    # know what type of model to add! 
    @user.subscriptions = [DailySubscription.new, WeeklySubscription.new]
  end

  ...

end
```

I think I am conceptually really missing something here but I can't figure it out.  Help!

Comment: Are DailySubscriptions and WeeklySubscriptions mutually exclusive? Can a user have more than one subscription of the same type? Perhaps what you want is for a User to have_one DailySubscription and have_one WeeklySubscription.

Comment: You could pass a local variable to the view instead of creating new subscriptions (leave those empty), unless there is more for the user to do than to check a checkbox.  In the create action, you can then read the checkbox value from the params hash and decide which subscription should be created.

Comment: @Jimmy.  The user could have both.  It is possible that the user could have more.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Makes sense but sounds slighty hackish no?  I was thinking I might be missing a key concept here that would fit better into the Rails Way (tm).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your description, your user has only two possible subscription choices: daily and/or weekly. Therefore you dont need to  have a has_many association because two has_ones would suffice(note polymorphic subscribeable below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :daily_subscription, :as => :subscribeable
  has_one :weekly_subscription, :as => :subscribeable
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscribeable, :polymorphic => true
  # type field is defined in the migration for Single Table Inheritance
end

class DailySubscription < Subscription
  # Business logic here 
end

class WeeklySubscription < Subscription
  # Different business logic here 
end
```

furthermore for the controller you just need to initialize User. Upon initialization, @user.daily_subscription and weekly_subscription will be null as determined by .blank? method. When you go ahead and create the user in the create method, you will need to populate these fields with instances of corresponding subscriptions.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @user = User.new
   # bam -- youre done.

 end
```

...

end

Comment: @jevy. What questions? P.S. Could you update your original question with information you put in the comments if it changes the description of data model, etc.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for.  Just to clarify, in the new (and edit) views I simply create checkboxes for these values which should automatically be populated.  In the create (and update) action, I'll have to check the params directly to see if the checkboxes were selected, and remove or create an association appropriately, which doesn't sound as automatic.

Comment: It all depends on what Daily vs Weekly subscription means model-wise. If these are basically flags, then maybe represent them as booleans in the User model. this way checkboxes will translate directly into your ActiveRecord. This works if there are only two types of subscriptions imho

Comment: I don't understand what polymorphism buys you here. Why not just do a has_a :daily_notification :as => :subscription ?